# Why can't I add items to an array if it is inside a singleton class?

Tags: arrays, swift, singleton

I have a singleton class which looks like this:

```
class DataAccess {
    var teamUrl = NSArray()
}
let sharedData = DataAccess()
```

This is saved as a `.swift` file.

I am trying to add an item to that array from one of my view controllers. The code I am using to try and add the item to the array is this:

```
sharedData.teamUrl.append(teamUrl.text)
```

I am receiving an error message though. The error message is:

```
'NSArray' does not have member names 'append'
```

I know that it is something to do with my singleton because I created an array in the view controller and changed the code correspondingly and it worked.

I also tried to change the Singleton class to this:

```
class DataAccess {
        var teamUrl = []
}
let sharedData = DataAccess()
```

I received the same error though.

I'm not sure why this isn't working. Please would somebody be able to explain where I have gone wrong?

Just to add, although I have referred to these as singletons, I'm not 100% sure that they are - its just the name they were referred to on a tutorial when I was learning about transferring data between different views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `var teamUrl = []`, try `var teamUrl: [String] = []`.  This will create a native Swift array, instead of an `NSArray`, and that has a `.append` method.

Comment: Yup. Or ` = Array<String>()`